# Emacs: How to make regexp search the default for C-s?

Tags: emacs, search, regex

How can I change Emacs so that the regexp search (instead of normal search) is the default?

I would like to be able to type `C-s [0-9]`, for example, and it takes me to the next number. Then, press `C-s` again, and it takes me to the next number.

I tried this:

```
(global-set-key "\C-s" 'search-forward-regexp)
```

But the repeated pressing of `C-s` does not work. It does find the first occurrence, but to find the second you have to re-enter the regexp `[0-9]` after pressing `C-s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close - use `isearch-forward-regexp` - note the 'i'.

Found via 'C-h k C-M-s' which is bound to interactive regexp search forward.